# Create c# request analogous to curl

Tags: c#, curl

I have a curl request that I am trying to replicate in a C# app. Request has the following structure:

curl "https://samplewebsite.com" --data 'data={a json data structure}'

When I insert this request in postman, I get the correct result. This is the code I used to replicate it:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var urlData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("data", json) };
        HttpContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(urlData);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("https://samplewebsite.com", content);
```

However every time I run this code I get an exception stating that a connection was terminated by host. What could be the difference between the two requests that causes this behaviour?

Comment: ```var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(yourEndPoint, new { data= yourJsonObjectHere}).Result;``` why you don't create anonymous object like this ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears the problem was in security protocol used. Changing it to Tls12 solved the problem for me